# php function breaking foreach loop

Tags: php, function, foreach

I'm trying to program a function to generate a navigation menu using values from a MYsql database. I have all the values and have stored them in arrays and I have tested the foreach loop for part of the code but if I try to put it in a function it breaks? I've searched around for an answer in documentation and have seen something about variables/arrays used outside a function not being allowed to be used inside a function but everything breaks even when i change it all up and use a different variable. Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Code below:

This works:

```
  <?php  

foreach($pageWithNoChildren as  $arrayofpageinformation) {
echo "<a href=" . $arrayofpageinformation['url'] . ">" . $arrayofpageinformation['linklabel'] . "</a></br>";
} 
?>
```

but this does not

```
     <?php  
      function buildMenu(){

  foreach($pageWithNoChildren as  $arrayofpageinformation) {
   echo "<a href=" . $arrayofpageinformation['url'] . ">" . $arrayofpageinformation['linklabel'] . "</a></br>";
  }
      };   
   ?>

   <?php buildMenu(); ?>
```

Neither does this

```
<?php  
          function buildMenu($pageWithNoChildren){

      foreach($pageWithNoChildren as  $arrayofpageinformation) {
       echo "<a href=" . $arrayofpageinformation['url'] . ">" . $arrayofpageinformation['linklabel'] . "</a></br>";
      }
          };   
       ?>

  <?php buildMenu(); ?>
```

or this

```
<?php  
      function buildMenu($items){

  foreach($items as  $item) {
   echo "<a href=" . $item['url'] . ">" . $item['linklabel'] . "</a></br>";
  }
      };   
   ?>

   <?php buildMenu($pageWithNoChildren); ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the last one doesn't work?  You may want to try that one again.

Comment: Last one should work. Try putting the echo text in a variable and return it from the function. And echo the function call.

Comment: first 2 will not work since in 1st scope of $pageWithNoChildren is not in the function. In the 2nd you are calling the function without param. 3rd is technically correct but check $pageWithNoChildren is getting passed to the function.

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty how can I check that please?

Comment: print_r($items) inside the function and see if it has data .

Comment: thank you, it seems to be working now. I'm not sure what i've done differently but yes the last one is now the one that is working and when i print_r inside the function it does indeed have data. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

For a function, if the variable is not global or is not set as an argument, the function will not be able to access it because functions have a local scope.

- The first one works simply because there is no function.
- The second does not work because the variable is neither global nor send as an argument to the function.  You could change it to this:

  ```
  <?php 
  function buildMenu(){
      global $pageWithNoChildren;
      foreach($pageWithNoChildren as  $arrayofpageinformation) {
          echo "<a href=" . $arrayofpageinformation['url'] . ">" . $arrayofpageinformation['linklabel'] . "</a></br>";
      }
  };   
  ?>
  <?php buildMenu(); ?>
  ```

  This tells the function to access the variable with a *global* instead of a *local* scope.
  You could also change it to your fourth example because that one should work.
- The third does not work for the same reason as the second.
- The fourth should work since when the variable is passed as an argument, it is accessible by the function.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding three non-working blocks,

1) Parameters not passed in both function and during the call.

2) Parameter not passed during calling.

3) It is working ! Check the keys again.